# Cleaning up a folder on a phone

Tags: android, firemonkey

first question on this site, if improper just tell me.

I am creating an app on an adroid platform. With this app I create some files and folders in the shared document folder.

What happens is this: with every build, at least with the *-cleaninstall* parameter set, it is impossible to overwrite existing files and/or folders. Even after deleting them on the phone.
Probably this is due to the fact that the filesystem thinks that the new build is not the original owner of the file/folder and is therefore not authorized to delete or overwrite.

As a bypass solution I am using an "appname" variable to create a folder to store data in, if necessary I update the "appname" variable so a fresh set of folders is created, based on the "appname" but this a pretty crooked way to work.

```
  DocumentFolder := System.IOUtils.TPath.GetSharedDocumentsPath;
  AppName        := 'ExpensesV2';
  AppFolder      := DocumentFolder+PathDelim+AppName; 
  if NOT DirectoryExists(AppFolder) then ForceDirectories(AppFolder);
```

Is there a proper way to really remove/clean up that specific folder OR get the proper autorisation.

Thank you for your valued responses!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify how you're going about creating the folders and writing the files. There are different mechanisms for doing so depending upon the type of file you want to write (media files, documents, generic files) and who you want to have access to it (public vs app private storage). There are also additional complications with permissions and things depending upon what OS version you're targetting.

Given the information available, the best I can suggest is having a look at these links:

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases

The latter gives some sample cases of types of file and purpose and suggests the mechanism to use to write/read it.

In the most general of senses, if you want to write to public external storage then use [getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)); but the warning note here is that the user can do as they wish with the files in the storage area; putting their own files there, renaming files, deleting files etc etc It is beyond the control of your app to manage.

If you want your app to manage the storage space properly then you need to use something like [Context#getExternalFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)), but then if you want those files to be externally visible you will have to share them with the system and look into things like [file sharing](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html) or content providers.

Comment: Thank you Simon, will lookup all references!!!